# Unable to send email from SSIS(Script Task) package to SharePoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: 2013, powershell, email

I am trying to send an email from a `SSIS package` to a SharePoint 2013 Document library. I am using a `Script Task` for this. The code I am using is as follows.

```
public void Main()
{
    String Sender = "first.last@something.this.com";
    String Recipient = "newtest@test.something.this.com";
    String SMTPServer = "mail.test.something.this.com";         
    String MailSubject = "User Details - Updated Records";
    String MailBody = "Please find the file attached herewith.";

    try
    {
        // Create an email and change the format to HTML
        MailMessage MailMessage = new MailMessage(Sender, Recipient, MailSubject, MailBody);
        MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Attachment AttachmentLocation = new Attachment("C:\\RootFolder\\SubFolder1\\SubFolder2\\NewData.csv");

        // Create a SMTP client to send the email
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer);
        //System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test\\first.last", "**********");
        mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        //mySmtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        MailMessage.Attachments.Add(AttachmentLocation);
        mySmtpClient.Send(MailMessage);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //An error occurred.
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace);

        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Example", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

But i am getting following error at `mySmtpClient.Send(MailMessage);`

> **Exception**
>
> Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>
> **Inner Exception**
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

**Mentions :**

1. I would like to mention that the SQL Server running my SSIS package
   is on `Domain 1` and the SharePoint Farm is on `Domain 2`.
2. I have checked the Drop folder also. But, the mail is not there.
3. I am able to send the same mail manually from my Outlook to the same
   Document Library.

Comment: The error message says unable to connect to the Email Server. Check mail server is accessible from the SSIS box. Check Firewall is not blocking etc.

Answer (score 0):

It was the silly one. The SMTP server i was using turned out to be wrong. Getting confused between many different environments i picked up the wrong SMTP server.